# Django Rest Framework limit the amount of items pulled from many to many serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is my model:

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
    ...
    associated_entities = models.ManyToManyField(db_index=True, to='Entity', through='EntityToCampaignMap')
    ...
```

A campaign can contain many many entities, but I want to limit the amount of entities I'm pulling with my serializer here:

```
class CampaignSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    associated_entities = EntityToCampaignMapSerializer(source='entitytocampaignmap_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Campaign
        fields = (
        'id', ... 'associated_entities', ...)
```

This pulls in as many entities as it can. Is there a way to limit it to say, 50 elements at most?

For clarifications, I'm not trying to paginate the Campaign model, that's already handled. I'm trying to limit the amount of entities pulled from a many to many relationship

I am also using custom mapping, so I need to use this serializer:

```
class EntityToCampaignMapSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    entity = EntitySerializer()
    relationship = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='relationship_label', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = EntityToCampaignMap
        fields = ('entity', 'relationship')
```

Comment: You might want to use pagination: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/

Comment: @jape I can paginate the model itself, so campaigns are properly paginated. But how do I paginate a many to many relationship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a different `source`.

```
class CampaignSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    associated_entities = SerializerMethodField('get_limited_number_of_whatever')
    ...

    def get_limited_number_of_whatever(self, obj):
          qs = obj.entitytocampaignmap_set.all()
          if not self.context['verbose']:
               # In case you don't want ALL E2C instances, limit the queryset
               qs = qs[:50]
          return EntityToCampaignMapSerializer(instance=qs, many=True).data
```

Comment: Where is the context for entitytocampaignmap_set coming from?

Comment: I'm getting this: Original exception text was: 'Campaign' object has no attribute 'get_limited_number_of_whatever'. Should this be under the serializer or Campaign model?

Comment: Indeed, the method source only works with SerializerMethodField. There is another way, but it isn't that pretty. Check out modifs.

Comment: I have a way to do it with properties in the model, but to toggle back and forth doesn't seem as straightforward as passing a parameter.

Comment: Sorry, I am not entirely sure what you are trying to say. What do you mean by "toggle back and forth" ?

Comment: Say I want to pull only 50 entities, and then I want to make the same request but request for all the entities. Is it possible to use 1 serializer to accomplish both tasks?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132931/discussion-between-adelan-and-stupid-fat-cat).